# Local Apache won't send PNGs correctly

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, php, png

Can't figure this out: Yesterday my local Apache config was sending PNGs just fine, today the browser is trying to decode them as JPGs and thus, only showing a "missing image" error despite returning a valid response from the server.

Opening the image in the browser using a direct file path works fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your apache server says the PNGs are actually JPEGs...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and eventually gave up understanding the "why." I suspect that if the php script can't find the cache dir that it just gives up somewhere in the middle of generating the header for the first alt image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized the problem was being caused by some code in my .htaccess file added as part of an "adaptive images" script I installed ([GitHub link](https://github.com/MattWilcox/Adaptive-Images)) to handle Retina display swap-outs. To be more exact, I didn't set the $cache_path variable in adaptive-images.php.